# Get emails list by applying advanced filter in gmail api

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am using gmail api to send and read emails.

I need to fetch all emails by applying some filter.

Ex: Suppose I need to get all emails between me and N other users(**user1@gmail.com**, **user2@gmail.com**, **.....**)

I need all emails from inbox and sent box both by applying some filter like this (all emails send by me to users or sent by users to me and don't include chats)

I was able to get all messages from inbox by following method.

```
public List<Message> getMessages(Gmail service) throws IOException {
    List<Message> messages = service.users().messages().list("me").execute().getMessages();
    return messages;
}
```

After doing some research I was able to apply query like this which returns all inbox messages send by **user1@gmail.com** excluding chats

```
public List<Message> getMessages(Gmail service) throws IOException {
    String query = "-in:chats from:user1@gmail.com";
    List<Message> messages = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ(query).execute().getMessages();
    return messages;
}
```

If I change query to this

```
String query = "in:inbox OR in:sent";
```

then I can get all emails in inbox and sent emails combined, but I am still stuck to filter conversation between given users and me only.

I searched a lot but did not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this filter:

```
String query = "(from:me AND to:user1@gmail.com) OR (from:user1@gmail.com AND to:me) AND (in:inbox OR in:sent)  AND -in:chats"
```

or

```
String query = "((from:me AND to:user1@gmail.com) OR (from:user1@gmail.com AND to:me)) AND (in:inbox OR in:sent)  AND -in:chats"
```

It is working from my side when test manually in Gmail desktop.

**Reference:**

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for answer, It's working. I have one more question. Is there any other way to create the query to make it more dynamic instead of writing manually.

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain further what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate the query at run time by passing list of users. I want to create a rest api with parameters (List<String> fromUsers, boolean includeChat, List<String> labels) and create the query by using these values

Comment: I want to know if Google api provides any way to crate criteria query or I have to manually write a method to generate the query.

Comment: Thanks for that information, If your main goal is to create query to be used for searching messages, then the only way to do that is to manually create a query syntax to be used as Q. See [Searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

Comment: You might also want to check [Managing Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings) if this might work on your goal. You can use Filters to configure advanced filtering rules for an account. Filters can automatically add or remove labels or forward emails to verified aliases based on the attributes or content of the incoming message.

Comment: Please do check what [filter criteria](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters#Criteria) you can configure, the criteria is quite basic so if you will require a complex filter conditions you will still need to create a query syntax for it